# SQL statement piped to conditional splitting result returned based on conditional

Tags: mysql, sql

(Couldn't think of a very good title for this)

Say I have a table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accts (
    name        varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    association varchar(255) NULL,
    type        varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (name, association)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

mysql> desc accts;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+
| name        | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |
| association | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |
| type        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+
```

I would like to query based on name, then from the results, grab the name relevant to the association if it exists, otherwise, grab the row with `NULL` for association

Example:

```
association = 'hello';
results = query('SELECT * FROM accts WHERE name = "world"');

/*
results = [
    { name: 'hello', association: null },
    { name: 'hello', association: 'earth' },
    { name: 'hello', association: 'world' },
]
*/

// here I want to grab the row where association matches,
// but default to association = NULL if none exists
// (the psuedo code below describes it programmatically)

default = null
for result in results
    if not result.association
        default = result
    else if result.association equals association
        return result

return default
```

It is simple to write with code, but I would prefer to wrap this up into a SQL statement, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM accts
WHERE name = 'world' AND (assocation = 'hello' or association IS NULL)
ORDER BY (association IS NOT NULL) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Or, alternatively:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM accts a
WHERE name = 'world' AND assocation = 'hello' 
UNION ALL
SELECT a.*
FROM accts a
WHERE name = 'world' AND association IS NULL AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM accts a2 WHERE a2.name = a.name)
```